# How can I count pixels with the graphics.h library in C language?

Tags: c

How can I find the area of ​​a polygon by counting the pixels inside a polygon whose corner coordinates are known, using the graphics.h library in C ?

Comment: Doesn't that library provide some *fill area* algorithm? You might just copy that one and instead of changing the pixel colour done there increment a pixel counter...

Comment: The area and the pixel count are two very different calculations. If you have the vertices in order, you can calculate the area easily. The number of interior pixels is not so easy. Which do you want?

Comment: I want to calculate the area of ​​a polygon whose corner coordinates are certain. @SimonGoater

Comment: [Classic formula.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

Comment: Please tell us, does your solution need to read pixels from the screen to find the area?